# How to pull a substring from Python Speech Recognition

Tags: python, string, input, substring, speech-recognition

I'm trying to pull a string from what is said by the user; however, I ran into a problem with my current solution using - re.

I was first trying to create a virtual assistant to find information on what the user requested, like a movie. Instead of having to run the speech recognition a second time to create a variable I wanted to pull it from the original input.  Here's what I mean:

```
if "about the movie" in command:
    about_the_movie(command)

def about_the_movie(command):
    m = re.match(r'(.*) about the movie (.*)', command)
    movie = m.group(2)
    movie.replace(" ", "+")
    url = ('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + movie + '&apikey=********')
    r = requests.get(url).json()
```

The issue that I'm running into right now is that if user says "about the movie 'The Dark Knight' it will throw a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.  I understand that it's because at that point m.group(2) doesn't exist but I'm not sure what I can do for a workaround.

I want to also add the ability to look up the definition of a word too but would run into the same issue if the user said "definition of automobile" vs "what's the definition of automobile"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your string contains quotes, then:

```
>> m = re.match(r"about the movie .(.*).", "about the movie 'The Dark Knight'")
>> print(m.group(1))
The Dark Knight
```

Answer (score 0):

So I kept messing around with this and realized that it would throw that error if there was a space:

```
m = re.match(r'(.*) about the movie (.*)', command)
```

vs

```
m = re.match(r'(.*)about the movie (.*)', command)
```

I appreciate the response though!